# Why does the app Automate require ADB?

Tags: adb, root-access, usb-debugging, automation, automate

I need to set up an app-killing service for **unrooted** Android 9 devices using [Automate](https://llamalab.com/automate/). The service has to launch automatically at device start and keep sending kill commands to selected system (!) services at regular intervals unless said services are in focus/in the foreground.

Unfortunately, setting up and running Automate seems unnecessarily [cumbersome](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/adb.html). I have used `adb` extensively, so no problem there. However, [step 5 in the setup manual](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/adb.html#setup) says

> 5. On the PC, execute the shell command `adb tcpip 5555`. **This step has to be repeated after every device reboot.**

[Also](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/adb.html#privileged_service):

> Once paired/authorized the service will start automatically when it’s first used, e.g. by a block using it, then run in the background **until** the system kills it, **the device is rebooted**, or the app is uninstalled or updated.

Having to hook up a *mobile* device to a PC after each and every reboot (e.g. due to empty battery) is completely impractical and contradicts the use of Android itself. Is there a way to set up Automate either 100% locally from within Android, or at least only once from a PC at the very beginning and then have the app run automatically even after a device reboot?

I have already set up a simple Automate flow as a minimal example and granted all necessary privileges, such as access to the SD card, executing shell commands, and access to Samsung accessibility service. Also, USB debugging is enabled in the developer options. But when running the flow, I get the following errors in the log output:

```
Flow beginning
Delay
App in foreground?
App kill
Failed to start privileged service
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Please execute: sh /sdcard/Android/data/com.llamalab.automate/cache/start.sh
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Service startup timeout
Stopped by failure
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151952/discussion-on-question-by-srhslvmn-why-does-the-app-automate-require-adb); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

[Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) does not require ADB nor a rooted device, but some features do, e.g. the [App kill](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/app_kill.html) block to kill the processes of other running apps.

Setting up ADB is indeed a bit cumbersome since it's an app developer feature, it's not designed for easy use by app users or by the apps themselves.

Setting up Automate "100% locally", i.e. without needing a USB connected PC, can only be done on Android 11 or higher by using the system "Wireless debugging" feature. To do so simply choose the "Android Debug Bridge (ADB)" option as the "Privileged service start method" in Automate setting, then follow the on screen instructions to enable the "Wireless debugging" option and pair Automate with the device. The pairing process only have to be done once, but enabling "Wireless debugging" has to be done manually after every reboot, unless you automate the procedure.

The logged error message means Automate can't access/start its "privileged service", e.g. that the [App kill](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/app_kill.html) block rely on, and tells you to execute the shell script to do so, this means you've selected the "Manually" option as "Privileged service start method". Try the "Android Debug Bridge (ADB)" option instead.

Comment: *"Setting up ADB is indeed a bit cumbersome"* => As I wrote, no problem here. I've been using `adb` a lot. With "cumbersome" I mean the requirement to hook up the device to a PC after every reboot. This is an impossible demand for mobile device usage.

Comment: *"The logged error message means Automate can't access/start its "privileged service", e.g. that the App kill block rely on, and tells you to execute the shell script"* => Can't Automate itself execute the shell script? There is explicitly an option to permit Automate to execute [shell commands](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/shell_command.html), which I've already enabled in the system app permission settings!

Comment: *"Automate does not require ADB nor a rooted device, but some features do, e.g. the App kill block to kill the processes of other running apps."* => This only [seems to be the case for Android 14+](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#kill-own-background-processes), but not for Android 9+ which is what this question is dealing with.

Comment: @srhslvmn As said, a PC is not needed on Android 11+ when using the system "Wireless debugging" feature. Automate will execute the commands in shell script when using the "Android Debug Bridge" or "Superuser" option as "Privileged service start method". Regular apps could only kill **background** processes prior to Android 14, i.e. the [App kill **background**](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/app_kill_background.html) block.

Comment: Sorry, but there seems to be a misunderstanding. *"Android 9+"* in the question means that a solution for Android 9 and higher is required (i.e. including version 9).

Comment: What happens when you force-close apps from the app info menu in the settings? Or kill background apps from the developer options? Does the touchscreen (i.e. user input) run with root provileges? Wouldn't it be possible to just emulate the force-close button press programmatically? Why all the hassle of trying to make `adb` work in the first place (to paraphrase the question topic)?

Comment: @srhslvmn When the buttons are clicked the the Settings app will call the System API that kills an app, so does the App kill blocks in Automate. The system, its touch screen component and the Settings app have "root" privileges. Yes you can simulate clicks on the "Force close" button, e.g. using the [Interact](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/interact.html) block, but that requires that the Settings app is shown on screen, calling the system API directly does not.

Comment: *"Yes you can simulate clicks on the "Force close" button, e.g. using the Interact block, but that requires that the Settings app is shown on screen"* => Is this possible without first unlocking the screen, either using built-in Android methods or some shady workaround/hack?

Comment: @srhslvmn No, the device has to be unlocked and the proper Settings page visible on screen.